# Using .get() to pull a Tkinter variable from another class

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a Tkinter application that requires parts of the user display to exist in two different class, both imported from another file. I need to take a piece of user input and pass it from one class to another. In the toy example below, the user is supposed to type something into `my_entry_input` which later the class `PullVariable` is supposed to access.

Code is below. I had a few thoughts, such as somehow using globals or creating a function within the original class to get the variables and then pass them back. In all cases, I get:

> AttributeError: type object 'Application' has no attribute 'my_entry'

The best solution I can think of is to create a function that responds to the binding, then pass the `.get()` to the other class from that function. My feeling is that tkinter doesn't like `.get()` in between classes.

Thanks to the community for your help.

MAIN

```
from import_test1 import *

root=Tk()
ui = Application(root)
ui.hello_world()
ui.entry()

pv = PullVariable()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

IMPORTED CODE

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):        
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Application init')
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent=parent
        self.parent.grid()

    def entry(self):
        self.my_entry = StringVar(self.parent)
        my_entry_input = Entry(self.parent, textvariable=self.my_entry, 
            width=16)
        my_entry_input.bind('<FocusOut>', self.show_entry)
        my_entry_input.grid(column=0, row=1)
        self.show_label = Label(self.parent, text = '')
        self.show_label.grid(column=0, row=2)

    def hello_world(self):
        print('hello world')
        self.hw = Label(self.parent, text='Hello World!')
        self.hw.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def show_entry(self, event):
        PullVariable(Application).find_entry()

class PullVariable:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        print('Pull initiated')

    def find_entry(self, event=None):
        self.pulled_entry = self.app.my_entry.get()
        self.app.show_label['text'] = self.pulled_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

`my_entry` is not a attribute of `Application` class, so you can't do `Application.my_entry`, by it is an attribute of instance of `Application` class, so you can do `Application().my_entry`. You can probably add either instance of `Application` or `my_entry` to the `__init__` method of `PullVariable`. I'll use the former.

```py
# ...
class PullVariable:
    def __init__(self, app): # add app here
        self.pulled_entry = app.my_entry.get() # use app here
        print(self.pulled_entry)
# and then
root=Tk()
ui = Application(root)
ui.hello_world()
ui.entry()

pv = PullVariable(ui) # supply PullVariable with instance of Application
```

Comment: Promising... can I pass `app` to another function inside the `PullVariable` class?

Comment: If you attach `app` to instance inside `__init__`. So `self.app = app`. I would recommend to learn the basics of OOP in Python before writing attempting to write `tkinter` application.

Comment: Not sure your condescension is warranted. I'm an ameteur but I'm not new to OOP. I'm just trying to learn about importing multiple classes and how I can get them to interact. You are new here so I won't downvote you, but I don't think it is the right way to conduct yourself. As an aside, your code idea doesn't work. If I do something like call a function inside of the PullVariable class after a binding it wants to reinitialize the class, which isn't going to work.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure I understood your question correctly. Can you maybe tell, what are you trying to achieve with maybe some more practical example? Do you just want to have two classes to have a reference to one object? What do you mean reinitialize class? Why can't you just pass reference to the constructors/methods?